# NodeFlutter Error - Type Null Is Not A SubType Of String

Tags: node.js, mongodb, flutter, express

I am creating an ecommerce application using node and flutter. I have created a new post request where users can create a new product review , everything is working fine when I try this request on postman but from frontend it's giving an error.

Error

[image: 1]

productController Code

```
const createProductReview = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  const { rating, comment } = req.body;
  try {
    const product = await Product.findById(req.params.id);

    if (!product) return res.status(404).json({ msg: "Product Not Found" });

    let user = await User.findById(req.user);

    const alreadyReviewed = product.reviews.find((r) => r.userId === req.user);
    if (alreadyReviewed) {
      return res.status(400).json({ message: "Product already reviewed" });
    }
    const review = {
      name: user.name,
      rating: rating,
      comment,
      userId: user._id,
    };

    product.reviews.push(review);
    product.numReviews = product.reviews.length;
    product.rating =
      product.reviews.reduce((acc, item) => item.rating + acc, 0) /
      product.reviews.length;

    await product.save();
    res.status(201).json({ message: "Review added" });
  } catch (e) {
    return res.status(400).json({ error: e.message });
  }
});
```

productModel

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const reviewSchema = mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    rating: {
      type: Number,
      required: true,
    },
    comment: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    userId: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);

const productSchema = mongoose.Schema(
  {
    userId: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    images: [
      {
        type: String,
        required: true,
      },
    ],
    reviews: [reviewSchema],
    description: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    rating: {
      type: Number,
      required: true,
      default: 0,
    },
    numReviews: {
      type: Number,
      required: true,
      default: 0,
    },
    price: {
      type: Number,
      required: true,
      default: 0,
    },
    countInStock: {
      type: Number,
      required: true,
      default: 0,
    },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);

const Product = mongoose.model("Product", productSchema);
export default Product;
```

reviewModel.dart

```
import 'dart:convert';

class Review {
  final double? rating;
  final String? comment;
  Review({
    required this.rating,
    required this.comment,
  });

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      'rating': rating,
      "comment": comment,
    };
  }

  factory Review.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return Review(
      rating: map['rating'] ?? '',
      comment: map['comment'] ?? '',
    );
  }

  String toJson() => json.encode(toMap());

  factory Review.fromJson(String source) => Review.fromMap(json.decode(source));
}
```

addProductReview.dart

```
void addProductReview({
    required BuildContext context,
    required String productId,
    required double rating,
    required String comment,
  }) async {
    final userProvider = Provider.of<UserProvider>(context, listen: false);

    try {
      Review review = Review(
        comment: comment,
        rating: rating,
      );

      http.Response res = await http.post(
        Uri.parse('$uri/products/$productId/reviews'),
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
          'ax-auth-token': userProvider.user.token,
        },
        body: review.toJson(),
      );

      httpErrorHandle(
        response: res,
        context: context,
        onSuccess: () {
          showSnackBar(context, 'Review Added Successfully!');
          Navigator.pop(context);
        },
      );
    } catch (e) {
      showSnackBar(
        context,
        e.toString(),
      );
    }
  }
```

addingNewReview screen

```
class CreateProductReviewScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String routeName = '/create-new-review';
  final String productId;
  const CreateProductReviewScreen({Key? key, required this.productId})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<CreateProductReviewScreen> createState() =>
      _CreateProductReviewScreenState();
}

class _CreateProductReviewScreenState extends State<CreateProductReviewScreen> {
  final TextEditingController ratingController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController commentController = TextEditingController();
  final ProductServices productServices = ProductServices();
  final _addNewReviewFormKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    ratingController.dispose();
    commentController.dispose();
  }

  void addNewReview() {
    if (_addNewReviewFormKey.currentState!.validate()) {
      productServices.addProductReview(
        context: context,
        productId: widget.productId,
        comment: commentController.text,
        rating: double.parse(ratingController.text),
      );
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: GlobalVariables.secondaryColor,
        title: const Text("Add New Review"),
      ),
      body: Form(
        key: _addNewReviewFormKey,
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
            horizontal: 10,
          ),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              const SizedBox(
                height: 15,
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 30,
              ),
              CustomTextField(
                controller: ratingController,
                hintText: 'Rating',
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 10,
              ),
              CustomTextField(
                controller: commentController,
                hintText: 'Comment',
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 10,
              ),
              CustomButton(
                text: 'Add',
                onTap: addNewReview,
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Seems like a dart error.

Comment: I think you have an error here:
`    const review = {
      name: user.name,
      rating: rating,
      comment,
      userId: user._id,
    };
` for comment

Comment: Please put the exception logs.

Comment: @shanshaji there is no exception

Comment: @Alaindeseine that's not the problem because backend is working fine problem is from the frontend I just can't figure it out

Comment: Error Fixed: Just had to replace this rating: map['rating'] ?? '', with rating: map['rating']?.toDouble() ?? 0.0 ?? '', in reviewModel.dart